# Creating a cloud-based streaming server using 2 Raspberry Pis

Tags: web-hosting, server, cloud, streaming

I have a project that aims to create a cloud-based video streaming server that runs on 2 raspberry pis. Originally I planned to use PLEX media server to present my files, and I would link my Pis together using Docker Swarm (plex will be hosted as a service on docker). My first problem arose when docker wouldn't allow my plex container to be used across the swarm.

I was just wondering if anyone had some ideas as to a better way to present videos across a network using cloud technologies.

Comment: Why 2 of them rather than just one?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's part of the project to use the processing power of multiple computers. In this example I guess it isn't actually necessary to use a Docker Swarm to simply send video to Plex, but it is a requirement.